# Is it a good practise store the checkout steps fields in php $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session, e-commerce, checkout

I have my e-commerce site with three checkout steps, each button to continue is a POST action and redirect to the next step:

[image]

[image]

if the user navigates by the checkout steps (click on the previous button for example), the form fields don´t show the data posted previously.

This form fields are shown empties:
[image]

I want to make that any information that a user fills out doesn't get erased when they navigate by the checkout steps.

**what is the best way to do this?** store the checkout steps fields in $_SESSION?

Something like this:
$_REQUEST['name_name'] = $_SESSION['contact_name'];

Thank you very much.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with storing the data in a session, but it is even better to save the data into a database and link it to the user. This way, if the user navigates away or the session times out, it can still be fetched as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Class that uses $_SESSION to store the data so you can use something simple like this:

```
// start checkout
$checkout = new checkout();
// to add data
$checkout->AddName() = $_REQUEST['name_name'];

// retrieve name
$name_name = $checkout->Name;

// empty checkout session on success
$checkout->reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use $_SESSION variables to save the data the user has entered.

You may want to use an object to encapsulate all the information so you can save it with a single assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use 3 divs : one for each step.

Then when first one is completed and submitted, I'd `post` the data using `AJAX`, hide the first div and show the second one, payment.